# Android: get Viewgroup from the view?

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

Is there any way to get the ViewGroup from a view? I'm trying to create a custom array adapter and it needs the viewgroup

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Depending on which `ViewGroup` you are after, you can get the parent of your view and cast it to a `ViewGroup`:

```
(ViewGroup)view.getParent() // this can be done to get any level in your view hierarchy
```

or you can cast the view itself as a `ViewGroup`:

```
(ViewGroup)view
```

Basically, find the view you want in your view hierarchy and cast it to `ViewGroup`